# Fixing an ImageView to right-most place in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

So, this is my current `LinearLayout`:
[image]

with the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Crime Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Crime date" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crime_police"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:src="@mipmap/handcuffs" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the closest I have gotten to my objective, which is to move the ImageView to the right-most in this LinearLayout. So that I can be able to create this following sample using a RecyclerView:
[image]

Is it possible to achieve this by using LinearLayout only? Or do I have to look into using other types of Layouts in addition to the LinearLayout which consists of `Crime Title` and `Crime date`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to change anything in your layout

Just Use [**`android:layout_weight="1"`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_weight) inside your second `LinearLayout` it will work

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Crime Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Crime date" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crime_police"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Bingo! It did exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks. Now may I kindly ask what the additional line of code does?

Comment: @Huzo check updated answer and check docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_weight

Comment: I think I have understood what it does, but I still can not understand why setting the second LinearLayout's weight to 1 (while the TextView has 0 weight as default) perform what I had wanted. Wouldn't this mean that the ratio only depends on second LinearLayout's size? But somehow the Image is at the right-most corner.

Comment: @Huzo you parent  `LinearLayout` orientation is `horizontal` by setting `android:layout_weight="1"` to your inner `LinearLayout` it will take 90% space of parent layout


Indicates how much of the extra space in the LinearLayout is allocated to the view associated

Comment: I see, but how is it 90%? The `LinearLayout` has weight of 1 and `ImageView` has weight of 0. So `LinearLayout` must occupy 100% of the space?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179543/discussion-between-huzo-and-nilesh-rathod).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/crime_police"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Crime Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Crime date" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crime_police"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if I'm not wrong than text will overlap the image if length of text increase

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Crime Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Crime date" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crime_police"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: if I'm not wrong than text will overlap the image if length of text increase

Comment: @NileshRathod yeah it's happens sometime :D updated it ;)

Comment: alignParentRight works only with RelativeLayout. You provided wrongly LinearLayout twice